# Titanium: Animation with rotation changes initial view location

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

Animating a view with a rotation set appears to change the location & orientation of the original view, BEFORE the animation starts.

In the example below I have 2 views set at the same location, view2 should start at the same location as view1 when the animation starts; but it does not! The rotation function in the animation causes the original view2 to be shifted... I would not expect this to be the case...

If the rotation is removed the animation behaves as it should do (the long duration enables you to see the change to the original view, before the animation starts).

```
var view1 = Ti.UI.createView({
    transform: Ti.UI.create2DMatrix().translate(100, 200),
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    left: 0,
    top: 0,
    backgroundColor: 'blue'
});
background.add(view1);

var view2 = Ti.UI.createView({
    transform: Ti.UI.create2DMatrix().translate(100, 200),
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    left: 0,
    top: 0,
    backgroundColor: 'green'
});
background.add(view2);

view2.animate({ 
    transform: Ti.UI.create2DMatrix().translate(300, 300).rotate(33),
    duration: 5000
});
```